# Django: How to format nested data, including a list of dictionaries, as multipart/form-data for posting?

Tags: python, django

How can I format nested data, including a list of dictionaries, as `multipart/form-data` for posting in Django?

```py
DATA = {
    "title": "Test Entry",
    "subcategory_id": subcategory.pk,
    "description": "Description for test entry.\n" * 2,
    "price": 150_000.00,
    "publisher": publisher.pk,
    "location": {
        "town": "Ant Town",
        "landmark": "Pink Poolside",
    },
    "cover": _simple_image(),
    "images": [_simple_image(), _simple_image()],
    "specs": [
        {"name": spec_field1.name, "value": "1000", "field_id": spec_field1.id},
        {"name": spec_field2.name, "value": "SSD", "field_id": spec_field2.id},
    ],
    "tags_ids": [tag.id for tag in TagFactory.create_batch(2)],
}

def test_something_doesnt_go_wrong(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=UserFactory())

        url = reverse("entries:entry-list")
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format="multipart")

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data["images"]), 2)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data["tags"]), 2)
```

This is the error I get when I run my test suite.

```
AssertionError: Test data contained a dictionary value for key 'location', but multipart uploads do not support nested data. You may want to consider using format='json' in this test case.
```

Is this even legal? Is the API badly designed (I'm wondering). What can I do here?

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to achieve this using `QueryDict`.

Comment: The question is, what does the recipient expect?  Multipart data is designed for HTML `<form>`s with simple `<input>` fields.  If you want to send a data structure, then you probably need to send JSON, as the assertion suggests.  In that case, you just have a long value.